# How was my call 'stong'?

Tags: tournament, nlhe

I was playing in a tournament, running well (2x average stack) and had a strong table image (knocked out a couple people).  Last hand before the second break, 4 hours in.  A middle position raises. I'm in late position and have AKo. Trying to be tricky and get to break with my large stack in tact,I decide to just call. One of the blinds call.

I end up making nothing and fold without spending any more money.  The blind wins with AJo after he flopped a jack.  During the break he asks what i had because he was going to reraise the mp raise but my call was strong. I  told him and he said he knew i had something.

Any insight on that? Complete BS?